# yum update keeps recreating CentOS7-Base.repo

Tags: centos7, yum

I configured yum on a CentOS7 box to use a repo on my network instead of going to the internet.
In /etc/yum.repos.d/ I only have internal.repo.

When I run yum update for the first time it works fine.
But it creates 6 files like CentOS-Base.repo, CentOS-Media.repo, etc.
Next time I run yum update it fails.
If I delete CentOS* from the folder, yum update works.

What's the right way to prevent these files from being recreated?

Comment: Rather then deleting the default repo files you should edit and disable them, I think.

Comment: Really - just disable them without deleting (set enabled=0 within each section)